# Filling in attributes from a different layer in QGIS batch mode

Tags: qgis, expression, batch, array, aggregation

I have a point layer with an `X,Y` field, containing the coordinates of each point separated by a comma.

I'm trying to batch process r.water.outlet based on these `X,Y` values from a different layer, the r.water.outlet tool requires entering the coordinates of the desired point, I'm trying to automate the process such that the batch processor automatically grabs `X,Y` values from the point layer instead of having to manually copy and paste `X,Y` for each row in the batch processor.

Comment: Hi Sky, welcome to GIS SE. Your question is unclear - in fact you don't have a question at all. Please provide more information to avoid to question being closed. See [tour]. I can't find any option for X Y input in r.waterhed, so not sure what you're speaking about. Provide a screenshot to show what you have and what exactly you miss. If your question is how to split an attribute field with combined XY values to two separate fields, than A) state so and B) have a look at field calculator.

Comment: My bad, I meant r.water.outlet, not r.watershed!

Instead of manually inputting my coordinates in r.water.outlet for each desired point, I want to grab the coordinates from a point layer that has a "X,Y" field. Copying and pasting each cell in the batch processor is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Batch Processing interface, instead of filling in the values manually, click <kbd>Autofill...</kbd> > <kbd>Add Values by Expression</kbd> and insert the following expression (replace `points` with the name of your point layer). It collects all points, using [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) function.

```
    aggregate ('points','array_agg',$geometry)
```

The coordinates of all points will automatically be added in the order they were created, corresponding to [`$id`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-record-and-attributes-id) (respectively variable [`@id`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables) since QGIS 3.28).

Use a similar method also to copy the value from the first row to all other rows: set `Drainage direcetion raster` for the first row only, than click <kbd>Autofill...</kbd> > <kbd>Fill Down</kbd> to avoid setting the same layer manually repeated times.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! exactly what I'm looking for!

I just have one small beginner question: in what order will the attributes be grabbed?

Comment: See updated answer